# I do not know why there is a zero in this formula.

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am currently studying the chapter on Numerical Differentiation in my book. However, I have encountered a section where a zero appears in the expansion, and I'm unsure of the reason behind its presence.

We take Taylor series expansion of the integral function

$g(x)=\int_{x_k}^{x}f(t)dt \hspace{0.2 cm}$ with  $\hspace{0.2 cm}g^{'}(x)=f(x),g^{(2)}(x)=f^{'}(x),g^{(3)}(x)=f^{(2)}(x)$

about the lower bound $x_k$ of the integration interval to write

$g(x)=g(x_k)+g^{'}(x_k)(x-x_k)+\frac{1}{2}g^{(2)}(x_k)(x-x_k)^{2}+\dots $

Substituting Eq together with $x=x_{k+1}$ and $x_{k+1}-x_{k}=h$ into this yields

$\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}f(x)dx=0+hf(x_{k})+\frac{h^2}{2} f^{'}(x_k)+\dots\hspace{0.2 cm}$

So I do not know why this zero appears.

Answer (score 1):

It is because $g(x_k)=0$.

If you're asking why $g(x_k)=0$, it's a special case of the rule $\int_a^af(t)\,dt=0$ (for any number $a$ and any function $f$).

If you're asking why they bothered to write it at all, as adding $0$ doesn't change anything, they put it there as a placeholder so that every term in the first equation has a corresponding term in the second equation, to make it easier to read. If they didn't write the $0$ then someone might wonder for a moment how $g(x_k)$ turned into $hf(x_k)$.